# Can we connect Finger print reader to android using "Android ODK Sensor Framework"?

Tags: android, android-layout, odk

I learning ODK with android Application and I know, to store the users information from android mobile to Google App server. you can view details of the users information using the [**Google fusion table**](http://www.google.com/drive/apps.html#fusiontables).

Open Data Kit (ODK) is a free and open-source set of tools which help organizations author, field, and manage mobile data collection solutions on online server. eg: Google App engine.
you can also view the received data in Google fusion table.

```
You can refer the link : http://opendatakit.org/       for more detail
```

My doubt is :

```
  ODK also has sensor framework to support out app with various sensor devices .
```

**I want to Know**

**Is it possible to connect fingerprint device using ODK sensor framework with our android application**

if NOT

**is it possible to get the an finger print image of a user using android mobile device.**

if YES

please send me a link to get the finger print image of a user while he registering his detail.